# How can I get my Spring Boot application to recognize this service?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm working on a Spring Boot 2.3 based application. I have a controller that currently has one autowired dependency:

```java
public class ValidationController {

    private ValidationService validationService;

    @Autowired
    public ValidationController(ValidationService validationService) {
        this.validationService = validationService;
    }
}
```

I have tests that run on this service and pass. I am attempting to add a second service to this controller:

```java
public class ValidationController {

    private ValidationService validationService;
    private TokenService tokenService;

    @Autowired
    public ValidationController(ValidationService validationService, TokenService tokenService) {
        this.validationService = validationService;
        this.tokenService = tokenService;
    }
}
```

When I do this, all of my `ValidationControllerTest` cases start failing. I found this message in the stack trace:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.auth.service.service.TokenService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

My `TokenService` interface is as follows:

```java
public interface TokenService {
    JsonWebToken getToken(User user, Account account);
}
```

The implementation is annotated with the `@Service` annotation:

```java
@Service
public class TokenServiceImpl implements TokenService {
    private final String url;
    private final String username;
    private final String password;

    public TokenServiceImpl(
            @Value("${service.url}") String url,
            @Value("${service.username}") String username,
            @Value("${service.password}") String password
    ) {
        this.url = url;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public JsonWebToken getToken(User user, Account account) {
        ...

        return jsonWebToken;
    }
}
```

My `ValidationService` looks very similar to my `TokenService` as far as annotations, but for whatever reason, Spring Boot can find my `ValidationService` just fine but my `TokenService`, which lives in the same place, is nowhere to be found.

How do I make sure that Spring Boot can find my `TokenService`?

---

**Thanks very much for the comments!**

> Can you double check that you bring up a spring application context in your tests?

It is my understanding that the `@WebMvcTest` annotation will load my application context, is that accurate? I have the following annotations on my `ValidationControllerTest` class:

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = ValidationController.class)
```

Is this sufficient to load the application context in my tests?

> Can you double check that this context does a component scan to the package where the `TokenServiceImpl` resides?

I am new to Spring Boot and still trying to grok component scanning. I have a `@SpringBootApplication` annotation on my main `AuthServiceApplication` class, which is in the `com.example.auth.service` package. I [read about component scanning here](https://www.springboottutorial.com/spring-boot-and-component-scan):

> If your other packages hierarchies are below your main app with the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation, you’re covered by implicit components scan.

My `TokenServiceImpl` class resides at  `com.example.auth.service.service.impl`, which I *think* means that it is within the hierarchy of the main app, so it should be covered by the implicit component scan. Is that accurate?

> Can you double check that `ValidationService` is not mocked (via @Mock annotation or something) somewhere in your test suite?

I do have the following in my `ValidationServiceImplTest`:

```java
@MockBean
private TokenService tokenService;
```

It looks like I am not using it at the moment. I will remove this `@MockBean` and see if that does the trick.

Comment: Can you double check that

1- you bring up a spring application context in your tests 
2- this context does a component scan to the package where the `TokenServiceImpl` resides 
3- `ValidationService` is not mocked (via `@Mock` annotation or something) _somewhere_ in your test suite.

Additionally: Do you get further errors after that stack trace that says something along `TokenServiceImpl` not being able to get created (due to maybe missing injected `@Value`s or something).

Comment: Can you post your test class?

Comment: Do You have any @Configuration class in Your project. Maybe you need to change a scope of component scan. Maybe the package of Service TokenServiceImpl  is not  scanned